# Ajax Push Engine (APE) - Sockets question

Tags: sockets, ape

I was looking into APE and they have a socket library that creates a socket server. Is there a tutorial on how to go about creating this so that the socket server is always running? and how well does it scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmm, not sure what are you looking for. The socket server looks pretty straightforward!

http://www.ape-project.org/docs/server/sockets/sockserver.html

About the scaling, I don't know, but they claim it scales (vertically) to more than 100,000 concurrent clients.

Comment: Yea i read that, but how do you always keep the socket server running?

Comment: Usually it's running as a daemon, like a web server

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it in Linux you might want to look up the nohup command
`nohup [command] &`